# Conditional distiribution of $X\mid X+Y=c$ with $X,Y$ iid $\sim \exp(1)$ distributions

Tags: probability, random-variables, exponential-distribution

I am supposed to find $$f_{X \mid X+Y=c},  \quad \mbox{ for }c>0$$ given that $X,Y \sim \exp(1)$ and independent. I have worked back and forth with convolution formula and Bayes theorem but without any progress.

We are looking for ; $\frac {f_{X,X+Y}(x)}{f_{X+Y}(c)}$ given $f_{X}=e^{-x} \chi_{\mathbb{R}_{+}}(x)$ and $f_{X+Y}(c)$ = $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x}\chi_{\mathbb{R}_{+}}(x)e^{-c+x}\chi_{\mathbb{R}_{+}}(c-x)dx$

I cant make sense of either numerator or denominator..

Comment: Since the most basic approach (ratio of PDF of X by PDF of X+Y) works, one is forced to ask: what exactly did you try? Or is your problem to compute the PDF of X+Y?

Comment: @Did dont I have $f_{X,X+Y}$ over $f_{X+Y}$?

Comment: Yes you have. Then why show **nothing** in your question?

Comment: @Did there, thats what I worked with. Can you spot the thing I messed up?
I dont even know how to express the joint distribution, I have  clue with the help of the answer below, anyway it would be nice if you could show what you mean in your first comment.

Comment: Sorry but I do not see $f_{X,X+Y}(x,c)$ nor $f_{X+Y}(c)$ in your revised question. The formula starting with $f_X=$ is absurd and the formula starting with $f_{X+Y}(c)$ is wrong.

Comment: @Did alright, what do you think it should be then? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution thats where I get my PDF from

Comment: Yeah, but this source certainly did not write $[f_X=e^{-x}]$, right?

Comment: @Did ah i need characteristic function on both expressions! That changes alot.

Comment: Indeed. $ $ $ $

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1238898/321264

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $U=X$ and $V=X+Y$ with $0< U< V$. Note that $V\sim \mbox{Erlang}(2,1)$ as [sum of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution) two iid $\exp(1)$ random variables. Then $X=U$ and $Y=V-U$ and $$J=\begin{vmatrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}1&0\\-1&1\end{vmatrix}=1$$ Hence $$f_{U,V}(u,v)=f_{X,Y}(u,v-u)\cdot1=e^{-u}e^{-(v-u)}=e^{-v}$$ with $0< u<v$. Thus $$f_{X\mid X+Y=c}=f_{U\mid V=c}(u\mid c)=\frac{f_{U,V}(u,c)}{f_V(c)}=\frac{e^{-c}}{ce^{-c}}=\frac{1}{c}$$ for all $0<u<c$. Hence $X\mid X+Y=c \sim \mbox{Uniform}(0,c)$.