# Calculating Conditional Probability $P(X<3|X+Y) $

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose that $ X,Y$ are independent unit $\text{Exp}(1)$ rv's find  $P(X<3|X+Y) $.

I am hoping to solve this problem, but I am actually not sure how to set up things correctly. I think we need to find the Density of $Z=X+Y$ and we can do something with that, but I am uncertain.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ given?

Comment: Yes, they are unit exponentials, so pdf is $e^{-x} $ supported on $[0,\infty)$

Comment: Hint: Calculate the density of vector $(X,Z):= (X,X+Y)$ and then use formula how to calculate $\mathbb E[h(X,Z) | Z]$ having density of $(X,Z)$. In your case $h(x,z) = 1_{x \le 3}$

Comment: @DominikKutek Can you please show it in answer how to do it using expectation?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1723646/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1238898/321264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tip: The sum of two independent exponential distributions has *this* pdf.

$$\begin{align}f_{\small X+Y}(z) &=\frac{\mathrm d~~}{\mathrm d z}\int_0^z\int_0^{z-x}\mathrm e^{-(x+y)}\mathrm d y\mathrm dx \\[1ex]&= z\mathrm e^{-z}\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant z}\end{align}$$

Which leads to the conditional distribution$$f_{\small X\mid X+Y}(x\mid z) = \dfrac{f_{\small X}(x)\,f_{\small Y}(z-x)}{f_{\small X+Y}(z)}\\\vdots$$

Comment: So I had actually gotten this far using convolution, as you did. However, I am a bit confused on how to actually calculate the probability of the event using this.

Comment: So $P(X<3)$ will be first calculating marginal of $x$ then setting its limits $0$ to $3$ right ?

Comment: Why from $0\leq z$ on the indicator for the pdf of the sum of two rvs?

Comment: $0\leqslant X+Y$ because they are both non-negative real-valued random variables.  That also means $0\leqslant X\leqslant X+Y$, Thus :  $$\mathsf P(X<3\mid Z) =\begin{cases}\int_0^3 f_{\small X\mid X+Y}(x\mid Z)\mathrm d x&:& 3\leqslant Z\\ 1 &:& 0\leqslant Z<3\\0&:& Z<0\end{cases}$$