# Generating a pair of exponentials with mean 1.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, exponential-distribution

According to Simulation by Ross, 5th edition p 72, it discusses how to generate a pair of exponentials with mean 1.

Step 1: Generate U_1, U_2 from U(0,1).

Step 2 : Let t := -log(U_1U_2)

Step 3 : Generate U_3 from U(0,1)

Step 4: X = tU_3, Y = t - X then they follow exp(1).

The book says that X|X+Y = t ~ U(0, t) when X and Y are independent and follow exp(1) but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: As written your Step 4 gives $X := tU_3$ and $Y := t(1 - U_3$). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, correct! Thank you.

Comment: Discussed at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1723646/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1238898/321264

Comment: @StubbornAtom I grasped the fact that X|X+Y = t ~ U(0,t) but I'm having struggle advancing to the next step : how does t U_3 and t - X follows exp(1)?